# External portable Touchscreen monitor (USB-C) on non-touch laptop

Tags: laptop, display, usb-c, touch

I have a laptop without touch screen (acer aspire E17 E5-774G-5660). It does come with a USB Type-C connector that supports USB 3.1 Type-C, Gen 1 .

I bought a portable touch monitor also equipped with USB-C connectors.Finally I have a BMAX laptop with touch screen and also USB-C connector.

When I hook up the monitor to the BMAX touch laptop it works fine. (including touch)

When I hook up the monitor to the Acer laptop, the monitor is not identified in WIN10 Home as an external monitor. However if I connect the portable monitor to the Acer via HDMI and provide a powersource for the monitor, then the external monitor is recognised by the Acer as an external monitor.

Are there special drivers perhaps needed to connect a touch monitor to a non-touch laptop? I don't need the touch function via the Acer laptop, but I just want to use it with one USB-C cable as an external monitor.
thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your Acer laptop does not support USB-C DisplayPort Alt Mode. That means its USB-C port cannot be used to connect displays<sup>1</sup>.

[As per Acer](https://us.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45406/%7E/usb-c-specifications-for-acer-aspire-e5-774-series):

> What features does my USB-C port support?
>
> - USB 3.1 Generation 1 with data transfer speeds up to 5 Gbps
> - Charging external devices via USB-C (5 V ; 3 A)

It should still be able to power the display though, but that may be a restriction of the display.

1: Except with USB graphics solutions of course

Comment: Ah I see, that explains a lot. Then I guess I need to revert to a HDMI cable and try to use the USB-C out from the Acer to power the display. Thanks a lot for the clear answer!